# JS: why this object property won't work and it only works if I put it inside one of the methods as a variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, object, properties

I have this form that replaces some text input box for the content of that input box. It does work as intended, but only if I create a variable inside the method, and not outside it as a property of the object.

So this is how I would like it to be (nombre as a property of the object reservasAPP):

```
<form id="form1" action="">
    <div class="row col-md-5">
        Horario: 09 horas 
        <span id="horario09"><input type="text" id="h09"></span>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="return reservas.guardarReserva();">Reservar</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="return reservas.cancelarReserva();">Cancelar</button>
    </div>
</form> 

var reservasAPP = {
    nombre: $('#h09').val(),
    guardarReserva:function(){
        var reservaConfirmada = $('#horario09').html('--> '+this.nombre);
        return false;
    },
    cancelarReserva:function(){
        var reservaCancelada = $('#horario09').html("<input type=\"text\" id=\"h09\">");
        return false;
    }
}
window.reservas = reservasAPP;
```

But this is how it actually works:

```
var reservasAPP = {
    guardarReserva:function(){
        var nombre = $('#h09').val();
        var reservaConfirmada = $('#horario09').html('--> '+nombre);
        return false;
    },
    cancelarReserva:function(){
        var reservaCancelada = $('#horario09').html("<input type=\"text\" id=\"h09\">");
        return false;
    }
}
window.reservas = reservasAPP;
```

The HTML form is exactly the same.

Why it doesn't work as a property?
If I try: `console.log(this.nombre);` I get nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your desired code will never work how you want it to, given upon object literal creation(what you're doing), the return value of the `.val()` call is set as the value.  This only happens once, hence further calls will always have the same value.

If you want the `nombre` property to evaluate to the value you wish, every time you access it, the `.val()` call must be shoved inside of a method with that property name, with the return value of the call:

```
var reservasAPP = {
    nombre: function () {
        return $('#h09').val();
    },
    guardarReserva:function(){
        var reservaConfirmada = $('#horario09').html('--> '+this.nombre());
        return false;
    },
    cancelarReserva:function(){
        var reservaCancelada = $('#horario09').html("<input type=\"text\" id=\"h09\">");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Lastly, depending on where your code is(since you don't specify, I don't know), the reason your `console.log()` call doesn't log anything is likely because you're calling the val code before the DOM has loaded, meaning it isn't there yet.  This thought is based solely on the fact that I see no `$(document).ready()` call in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm just learning JS, the code I've posted here is all the code there is: just two files, un JS and one HTML that calls the JS file in order to test this.

Comment: @Rosamunda Welcome; glad I could assist.

Answer (score 1):

It is working, but maybe is not what you are expecting.

Here is JSFidle to check it.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pablitoAM/e3hyqyd5/)

Check the console.

The problem is, when you create the object reservasAPP, you assign the field value to 'nombre'.

So if you change the input of the field and press 'Reservar' it will keep the previous value.

If you want to store in 'nombre' the current value of the field, you should apply a function like:

```
nombre: function(){
    return ($('#h09').val() || '');
}
```

And do not forget that now nombre is a function and should be called with () at the end.

```
guardarReserva:function(){
    var reservaConfirmada = $('#horario09').html('--> '+this.nombre());
    return false;
}
```

And finally:

```
console.log(window.reservas.nombre())
```

Comment: It isn't; your fiddle executes onload, and there's no evidence the OP's code does.